# antlr4 and string template groups and rewrite option in grammar

Tags: url-rewriting, antlr4, stringtemplate

In ANtlr3 I could specify the template group from the parser. The grammar itself had the following options

```
options {
    output=template;
    rewrite=true;
    language=CSharp4;   
}

parser.TemplateGroup = template;
```

How is this done in Antlr4 and ST4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR 4 does not have an `output` option (or `rewrite` option). In ANTLR 4, you would implement a listener for the parse tree automatically generated by the grammar, and perform all of the StringTemplate operations within the listener.

Comment: Are there any examples or reference code to illustrate this?